# Allow user select between different charts

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I've created several gvis Geo charts which are displayed in the same tabpanel and I would like the user to be able to select between the chart using a select box or similar however I can't get the function to work.

Can anyone assist?

**ui.R**

```
htmlOutput("schoolaid"),
br(),
htmlOutput("income")
```

Is there a straightforward way to have the user select between the  "schoolaid" and "income" outputs?

Comment: You can either use `conditionalPanel` to display an output based on a condition, or use `renderUI` and server end logic (for example, use `ifelse`) to render output based on user selection.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've tried a few option for conditional panel but I can't seem to get this to work. I've code like follows

Comment: #mainPanel(
 id = 'stuff',
selectInput("stuff", label = h5("Select to display Crime, School Aid or Salary data"),  choices = list("Crime", "School", "Income")),
                    
conditionalPanel('input.stuff === "Crime"',htmlOutput("crimehotspots")),
conditionalPanel('input.stuff === "School"',htmlOutput("schoolaid")),
conditionalPanel('input.stuff === "Income"', htmlOutput("income"))),

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that might help you.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("select", "Select a graph", c("mtcars", "cars"))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         conditionalPanel("input.select=='mtcars'",
                          plotOutput('mtcars')),
         conditionalPanel("input.select=='cars'",
                          plotOutput('cars'))
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$mtcars <- renderPlot({
        plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$disp)
    })   

    output$cars <- renderPlot({
        plot(cars$speed,cars$dist)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I got it to work based on this. One of the key problem i had was layering a mainpanel inside a TabPanel which was causing all sorts of issues